[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response (258)')
I'm trying to integrate an application with the Azure database but I'm facing some difficulties. The application uses the Python language with the Django framework.
Here is the application's settings.py:
DATABASES = {

'default': {

'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',

'NAME':'etsrooms-d1-bd',

'USER':'admin.gabriel',

'PASSWORD':############',

'HOST':'tcp:etsrooms-d1-server.database.windows.net',

'PORT':'1433',

'OPTIONS':{ 'driver':'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',

},

},

}

I ran this command in the terminal:
python manage.py migrate

And I got this error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].  (258) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response (258)')

I already checked the ODBC drive
When running the command I expected to have a connection to the database

is it reachable when you ping the server with the given port?

Make sure you install Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server and provide login details correctly.

@Gabriel Pimentel Da Silvav are you using pyodbc,pymssql packages? using Azure SQL Server, Azure MySQL flexible Server  etc?


[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response (258)')

The above error occurs due to network issues and also check with the firewall settings. Verify the version of ODBC driver. To connect with the database try with the below code, it has successfully connected the Azure SQL Server and retrieves the data stored in db as shown in the output below.
import pyodbc

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': 'admin02',
        'PASSWORD': *****,  
        'HOST': '<host_name>.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}

db_settings = DATABASES['default']

try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        driver=db_settings['OPTIONS']['driver'],
        server=db_settings['HOST'],
        database=db_settings['NAME'],
        user=db_settings['USER'],
        password=db_settings['PASSWORD'],
        port=db_settings['PORT'],
    )

    print("Connected to the database successfully!")

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error connecting to the database:", e)

Output:

